# #including a header from the previous directory (../)

Tags: c++

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a folder called Agui which is the lib's folder. In that folder there is another folder called Widgets. I want a file from Agui/Widgets to #include base.h from Agui folder. How should I do this so that it remains cross platform? Should I simply include `<Agui/base.h>` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#include "../base.h"`. And yes, that is portable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#include "../base.h"
```

From your `Agui/Widgets` folder. It should work. It should be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Better is

```
#include "Agui/base.h"
```

or

```
#include "../base.h"
```

depending of whether your library root or current folder are added to the include search path.

Angle brackets are reserved for system libraries (although one can actually use any kind of them).

Answer (score -2):

Its better to have the path setup in $PATH and in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. By doing the above, you can just refer to the header file :

```
#include <base.h>
```

This will help to configure/run in any platform

Comment: Neither PATH nor LD_LIBRARY_PATH are searched for include files.

Comment: @AProgrammer.. True.. I forgot that .. thanks for correcting :).